# Can't write statements inside methods. Functioning of java classes. "error: ";" expected"

Tags: java, class, methods

I've spent hours trying to solve this problem, with other posts' and google help, but to no avail.

Basically I can't write statements in methods of the PESO class

```
public class TEST {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    int resp = 0;
    int resp2 = 0;
    PESO t = new PESO();
    double g = 0;

   g=teclado.nextDouble();
   t.setLibras(g);
   t.KgaLibras();
}
}
```

---

```
public class PESO {

private double pesoKg;
private double pesoLibras;

public double KgaLibras(){
    pesoLibras = 0,453 * pesoKg;
    return pesoLibras;
}
}
```

I've tried changing the variables from public to private and viceversa, checking that all variables are declared where they ought to, I read that code can't just "float around" in a class and copied the structure of other code that worked. The moment I coded something into the method netbeans began throwing "error: ";" expected" type messages.

I know this is really basic advice I need. I'll be really thankful for anyone who can help me :)

Comment: Java uses . for point-separator instead of comma. So instead of `pesoLibras = 0,453 * pesoKg` you should have `pesoLibras = 0.453 * pesoKg;`

Answer (score 4):

The issue is you are putting the "," for the decimal separator. Most programming languages are ASCII and English, so you must use the "." for the floating point value.

The Java compiler is confused by the comma, thinking you might be putting a list where you cannot actually put a list.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answer. Java uses the dot for decimal separator and the compiler is throwing an exception.

> `.`   placeholder for decimal separator
>
> `,`   placeholder for grouping separator

From [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html)